# Para que serve/o que faz o método bincount do numpy?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

Eu li a documentação mas não entendi o que faz:

```
print(np.bincount(np.array([0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 7])))
```

A saída é:

```
[1 3 1 1 0 0 0 1]
```

Answer (score 4):

Esse método conta a ocorrência de cada método no array.

```
o número 0 aparece 1 vez 
O número 1 aparece 3 vezes 
O número 2 aparece  1 vez 
o número 3 aparece 1 vez 
0
0
0
```

Esses zeros é até chegar no último elemento uma vez que o vetor de saída, por padrão, é do elemento length max de array + 1.

```
o número 7 (último elemento) aparece 1 vez
```

Comment: você consegue ver alguma utilidade prática para o método bincount?